# Show div on scroll 200px but hide it on click

Tags: javascript, html

I have a div element #offer that is hidden by default and that is displayed on scrolling 200px from top, the div is being hidden once a user scrolls up again.

The following code does this just alright:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();   
    if (y > 100) {
        $('#offer').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#offer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

I would like to add an **option to hide the div manually simply by clicking on #hide-now div**. I have tried to use the following piece of code. Even though this hides the div #offer, the div is being displayed immediately again (because the scroll distance from top is more than 200px). What tweak in a code do I need to do to get this working?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#hide-now").live('click', function () { 
$("#offer").slideUp("slow");
});
});
```

Any ideas how to solve this? Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: this won't solve this particular problem, but use `on()` instead of `live()`.

Comment: Also, you can short-hand `$(document).ready()` by passing a function to jQuery like so: `$(function() { … });`

Comment: really appreciate your comments and the solution below. One question: when I hide it manually, in chrome the whole page jumps down by lets say 150 px. Now sure what is the cause of this. In IE its okay, not in Chrome though. Just wondering whether you see any reason why this is hapenning...

Comment: This is happening in http://jsfiddle.net/HpC36/1/ (and not http://jsfiddle.net/HpC36/0/) because of `href="#offer"`: when clicked, the browser is scrolling down to the position of `div#offer`. In v0, the `href="#nabidka-zajezdu"` has no anchor to scroll to, so it doesn't move.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So create a Boolean (for example, `show`) and check that Boolean before you perform the `fadeIn` action for your `scroll` handler.

So,

```
var show = true;
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();   
    if (y > 100) {
      if(show){
        $('#offer').fadeIn();
      }
    } else {
        $('#offer').fadeOut();
    }
});
```

Then, if they `click`,

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide-now").live('click', function () { 
    $("#offer").slideUp("slow");
    show = false;
  });
});
```

As with the others, I recommend using `on` instead of `live`.

Comment: I am sure all the solutions above would get the job done, i have picked yours and its working....thank a lot. Although there is one bug, one I click the "hide now div", the div disappers but i am noticing that the page srolls down itself a little bit...this is particulary hapenning in chrome, any thoughts on this?

Comment: No problem; glad it worked. I don't know why it would do that if it didn't happen before, as the only thing I did here is slightly modify the control flow, which should have no impact on the actual appearance of the page. It could have something to do with the `live`. Since you're using jQuery, I would recommend just doing `$("#hide-now").click(function(){...});`.

Comment: yes, I have just changed it, but this bug persists. Well in fact it have behaved the same way before too. The page simply jumps about 200px down on  the manual close.

Comment: It could be because you have `#offer` `slideUp()` instead of `fadeOut()` like your scroll function; try changing the manual to `fadeOut()`.

Comment: nope, no change. It is weird that it behaves correctly in IE but does this "jump down" in Chrome

Comment: sure, I have made the simplier version: http://jsfiddle.net/HpC36/ ... but it seems like it does not jumps down over there

Comment: I have just noticed one thing...in this file (http://jsfiddle.net/HpC36/1/) it jumps down, not in the previous one, it is probably something with the ids and classes, isnt?

Comment: It could be, but there's only one thing I can really think of that would cause your issue, and it can't really be fixed: when you `hide()` (`fadeOut()` is just a gradual `hide()`) the `div`, you're not really 'hiding' it; you're removing it from the page, which will change the page height, causing the 'jump' you're experiencing.

Answer (score 0):

I'd add a class to the div once it's been hidden, and then check if that class exists inside the scroll event handler. Try this out:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#hide-now").live('click', function () { 
    $("#offer").slideUp("slow").addClass("manually_hidden");;
  });
});
```

Then inside the scroll handler:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
  var y = $(this).scrollTop();   
  if (!$("#offer").hasClass("manually_hidden")) {
    if (y > 100) {
        $('#offer').fadeIn();
    } else {
        $('#offer').fadeOut();
    }
  }
});
```

Hope this helps! Also, I agree w/ the other comment to avoid using .live - .on or just a .click ought to do it.

Comment: `$("#offer").slideUp("slow"); $("#offer").addClass("manually_hidden");` can be chained together for simpler code.

Answer (score 0):

Set a flag when #offer is manually hidden (say, with a class):

```
$(function() {
    $("#hide-now").on('click', function () { 
        $("#offer").slideUp("slow").addClass('hidden');
    });
});
```

Then check for the flag:

```
$(document).scroll(function () {
    var y = $(this).scrollTop();   
    if ( ! $(this).hasClass('hidden') ) {
        if (y > 100) {
            $('#offer').fadeIn();
        } else {
            $('#offer').fadeOut();
        }
    }
});
```